# Why do makefiles sometimes have 'true <filename>' as part of the build script?

Tags: makefile

For example:

```
# Some stuff

all: some dependencies
    @$(CC) -o foo.o foo.c
    @true foo.o
    @some other operation
```

What purpose does the 'true foo.o' line serve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically this is output from a Makefile generator such as `automake`.  The `true` will be replaced with an actual command on platforms which require it.  The most common case is platforms which don't maintain static archive indexes automatically; the code will look something like

```
foo.a: foo.o bar.o baz.o ...
        ar rv foo.a foo.o bar.o baz.o ...
        true foo.a
```

but on some platforms (those without either System V or GNU `ar`) it will instead be

```
foo.a: foo.o bar.o baz.o ...
        ar rv foo.a foo.o bar.o baz.o ...
        ranlib foo.a
```

The reason it's not simply removed is that it's a lot easier in `m4` and other macro processors to substitute text on a line than it is to conditionally delete the line.  (It can be done, but advanced `m4` hackery has been known to cause insanity.  :)

Comment: You're half-right. Substitutions of variables such as `@RANLIB@` to `ranlib` (or `true`) are not usually done by m4, but instead by `config.status`, an `awk`-powered shell script that is created by `configure` as it finishes its run. It is hard to delete lines by substitution (`automake`'s conditionals are implemented by defining substitutions that expand to either an empty string or a `#`, commenting out the line). Replacing `@RANLIB@` with `#` is unsafe in general, so it is replaced with `true`.

Comment: True, `config.status` actually uses `sed` for that; I was actually thinking of `automake` creating `Makefile.in` from `Makefile.am`, which I don't reclal if it uses `m4` or `sed`.  (The example I used is admittedly more apropos to `config.status`.)