# true command in GNU-make rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working on the Makefile someone else in my lab wrote, and I see a command called `true` in some rules:

```
other_rule_A: YYY force_it
          ....
other_rule_B: XXX force_it
          ....

force_it:
          true
```

What does true mean here? Is it a command run by the subshell? What would happen if I replace it by false? Is `true` a binary invoked by the shell?

For reference, I found this other question in Stackoverflow: [Why do makefiles sometimes have 'true ' as part of the build script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239836/why-do-makefiles-sometimes-have-true-filename-as-part-of-the-build-script), but I don't think command is related to the command they cover in that thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`true` is a command (usually the executable `/bin/true`, but often also a shell builtin) that does nothing and returns success.  If you were to replace it with `false`, the `force_it:` rule would always fail and thus stop the make process at that point.

The difference between having this `true` action and having a `force_it:` rule with no action is that with no action, there might be some other `force_it:` rule with actions added elsewhere in the makefile.  With a `true` action, you know that there can be no other action -- if another action was added, you'd get a make error.

Comment: +1 also note `:` (just a colon) as a shell built-in with practically the same semantics.